# Retrieve string from textBox and pass it as int to stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I want to add a new record into my dataset using the next piece of code. The stored procedure get data from another form named 'AddStudentDialog' that has several textboxes

```
addStd = new AddStudentDialog();
addStd.Show();

studentTableAdapter.Insert(int.Parse(addStd.tb1.Text), addStd.tb2.Text, addStd.tb3.Text, addStd.tb4.Text, addStd.tb5.Text);
studentTableAdapter.Fill(studentDataSet.Student);
```

This is a piece of code in 'AddStudentDialog' form that refers to textBox1 sending string to my stored procedure above that I'm trying to convert to integer.

```
public TextBox tb1
{
    get
    {
        return textBox1;
    }
}
```

I experienced problem when I run an application due to an error when converting string to integer. Dows anyone has an idea how to solve it?

This is how I wrote this stored procedure in Visual Basic and it works perfect.

```
StudentTableAdapter.Insert(CType(AddStudentDialog.TextBox1.Text, Integer), AddStudentDialog.TextBox2.Text, AddStudentDialog.TextBox3.Text, AddStudentDialog.TextBox4.Text, AddStudentDialog.TextBox5.Text)
StudentTableAdapter.Fill(StudentDataSet.Student)
```

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET to connect to your db ?

Comment: Maybe you should check your input before converting a string to an int. You can start by using `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`.

Comment: Have you checked whether AddStudentDialog.TextBox1.Text has integer value? Best way is to first take them in variables, carryout type checking and then pass it on to proc.

Comment: what exact error (exception) are you getting?

Comment: I have also tried to put value from AddStudentDialog.TextBox1.Text to a variable in this way but the same happens:
`int intID;
        string stringID;` and 
`public int Id
        {  
            get
            {
                stringID = textBox1.Text;
                intID = int.Parse(stringID);

                return intID;
                
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this using TryParse method and this is how the code looks like.

'AddStudentDialog' which sends the values to the stored procedure (only textBox1 sends integer, other text boxes send strings):

```
    public int id;
    public int intID;
    public string stringID;
    bool res;

    public AddStudentDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void IntToString()
    {
        stringID = textBox1.Text;
        res = int.TryParse(stringID, out id);

        if (res == true)
            intID = id;
    }

    public int tbox1
    {
        get
        {
            return intID;
        }
    }
```

Stored procedure:

```
AddStudentDialog addStd = new AddStudentDialog();
        addStd.ShowDialog();

        addStd.IntToString();

        studentTableAdapter.Insert(addStd.tbox1, addStd.tBox2.Text, addStd.tbox3.Text, addStd.tbox4.Text, addStd.tbox5.Text);
        studentTableAdapter.Fill(studentDataSet.Student);
```